# How to get a linear map with specified kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This is more of an abstract question. Let $U, W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. I’m thinking about how one might get these subspaces to “interact” or be “paired up” in some way. The natural thought I had was to find a linear map $T$ from $V$ to itself so that $\ker T = U$ and $\text{im} \, T = W$. Then the rank-nullity theorem implies that we need the dimensions of $U$ and $W$ to add up to $\dim V$. So this is a constraint. One reason I was considering such a map is that, by the First Isomorphism Theorem, $V/U \cong W$, so we can think of $T$ as partitioning $V$ into identical copies/pieces of $U$, and each of these pieces is uniquely associated with a vector in $W$. So in a sense $U$ is sent into every point of $W$.

How might we find such a linear map? Does it matter whether or not $U, W$ intersect at a point other than zero, i.e. does it matter whether $U + W$ is a direct sum?

Comment: If you only fix one subspace $U$, then you can simply use the quotient map $f: V \to V/U: v \mapsto [v]$ which has $U$ as its kernel, or you can use the inclusion map $i:W \to V: v\mapsto v$ which has $W$ as its image. If now $V/U \cong W$, compose these to maps to get $T:V\to V$ that has kernel $U$ and image $V$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as $\dim W+\dim U=\dim V$ it is always possible to find such a map, since two linear spaces are isomorphic whenever they have the same dimension.

Suppose the equality holds, then $V/U\cong W$, and the composite map $T:V\to V/U\to W\to$ is always such that $\ker T=U$ and ${\rm im}\ T=W $. In this composite, $V\to V/U$ is the natural projection, $V/U\to W$ is the isomorphism, $W\to V$ is the inclusion.

This argument says $\dim W+\dim U=\dim V$ is sufficient for such $T$ to exist. The converse is obvious as you have observed. Hence we conclude:

> Such $T$ exists $\iff\dim W+\dim U=\dim V$.

---

**Some comment, since I sensed in your question that you are looking for some geometric insight into understanding linear spaces by studying linear maps on them:** You may think this is too easy. Indeed it is. The reason is that linear spaces are isomorphic whenever they have the same dimension. And the isomorphism can be given by (when using matrix to represent a linear map) any invertible matrix. The problem is that they are not "natural", and hence these maps are usually not very meaningful and does not provide any insight of the structure of the spaces you are studying.

However, in practice, natural maps are favored. So your question would be more interesting if you impose some more conditions on $T$ or $U$ or $W$.

---

For example, consider this new question:

> Can we find a linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $\ker T=U,\ {\rm im}\ T=W$, and $T(w)=w$ for all $w\in W$? In other words, $T$ annihilates $U$ while leaving $W$ intact.

Let's try to find a necessary condition for such $T$. Suppose it exists. Then

1. $\dim V=\dim U+\dim W$ as usual.
2. If $v\in U\cap W$, then on one hand, $T(v)=0$ because $v\in U$; while on the other hand, $T(v)=v$ because $v\in W$. Hence $v=0$. This means $U\cap W=0$ and $U+W$ is a direct sum $\implies\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W=\dim V\implies U\oplus W=V$.

You see, by imposing one more condition on $T$, it is necessary that $U,W$ must be the direct summands of $V$, and not just that their dimensions add up to $\dim V$. Infact the converse is true (which could be an easy exercise). Hence

> Such $T$ (with the extra requiment that $T(w)=w,\ \forall w\in W$) exists $\iff V=U\oplus W$.

A more insightful exercise is the following:

> For a linear map $T:V\to V$, prove that $T^2=T\implies V=\ker T\oplus{\rm im}\ T$. Conversely, if $V=U\oplus W$, then there exists a linear map $T$ such that $T^2=T$, and $\ker T=U$, ${\rm im}\ T=W$.

This $T$ is "natural" because it represents a projection onto $W$, and this gives a geometric interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment at the end. Could you give a short/rough idea or description of what it means to be "natural" and why this might be more insightful than considering things like what I did? Is it related to the fact that a linear map can be specified by multiple different bases, so there is no "uniqueness" in a sense?

Comment: @twosigma I'll try to think of an example...but maybe not right away. (Just had a failed attempt).

Comment: @twosigma Basically yes, a linear map can be determined by its behavior on a basis. And as long as you send a basis to an linearly independent set, the map is injective. If in addition, the target space has the same dimension, then you get an isomorphism. There is too much "freedom" in this. But if you impose more conditions on $T$, the question may get more interesting.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I might think about that when I have some more knowledge of linear algebra or algebra in general.

Comment: @twosigma I added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! My response to the exercise: ($\implies$) if $\ker T \cap \text{im} \, T \neq 0$ then $T(Tx) = 0$ for some $Tx \neq 0$, so $T^2 \neq T$. ($\impliedby$) Write each $v \in V$ uniquely as $v = u + w$ for some $u \in U, w \in W$ and define $Tv = w$; this is linear with $\ker T = U$ and $T^2 = T$.

Comment: ... and $\text{im} \, T = W$.

Answer (score 4):

As you state yourself, if such a map exists then $V/U \cong W$. So let's assume this.

First define $f$ as the quotient map
$$f: V \to V/U: v \mapsto [v]$$
which clearly has $U$ as its kernel. then define $i$ as the natural inclusion
$$i:W \to V: v\mapsto v$$
which obviously has $W$ as its image.

Then compose them to get
$$T: V\to V/U\cong W \to V$$
with the desired kernel and image.